# IPV6 Support For Cisco Nexus Switches

Tags: cisco, juniper, brocade, hp-procurve, netgear-prosafe

Does CISCO Nexus 3548P-10G L3 Switch Supports IVP6? What are some other alternative L3 Switches with same or slightly higher hardware configuration as CISCO Nexus 3548P-10G and IPV6 support

Comment: Surprisingly (at least I was surprised), it does not run any v6 routing protocols.  So I'd say support was "limited."   Other product recommendations are off-topic for this forum.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm responding because you're asking for alternatives. Have you considered the Brocade VDX 6740 or 6740-T? Both come with a very similar CLI to the Nexus, and are extremely affordable when compared to the N5K, yet way more solid than the N3K.

They also come with the layer 3 capabilities available off the bat. No need for additional licensing or hardware modules for routing.

Comment: Product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, as they are on most SE sites. There is [hardwarerecs.se] for this sort of thing.